# Listview to cardview in android

Tags: android

now I just got listview in android layout now i want to add cardview to this to show list of cardview.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/clistview">
            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

    //java code 

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivityCourseListView.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,adapterlist);
                clistview.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.e("Course ListView","Courses"+adapterlist);
```

Comment: Use custom adpter and in adapter's xml , put whole layout inside CardView...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a normal list view. You have to use a custom listview for this. Here is a tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By_1tpPDt4g